# Problems with body.findText in Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a Google doc which was created in Word and imported.  I want to locate a 'marker' in the text so that I can insert a table at that point.  However, I am unable to progress because my script keeps falling over at the "findText()" point.  I have looked at a number of answers to similar problems on here and used what I think are identical methods, but it still falls over!

Rather than post code here, it seems clearer to post a screenshot of exactly what I get when I attempt to run the script.  The first two items in the execution log prove that a) the document is being opened correctly and b) that the body is being correctly identified.  There is definitely a "$" sign later in the text, so why am I getting the error?

[image: Screen dump of error]

#### Script

```
var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/###/edit");
var body = doc.getBody();
var tblLoc = body.findText("$");
console.log(tblLoc)
```

Comment: No code=No Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- From your following image,

  [image]

  - I thought that the reason of your issue is due to `$` of `body.findText("$")`.
  - In this case, I think that it is required add `\\` like `body.findText("\\$")`
- The method of `findText()` returns the object of `DocumentApp.RangeElement`. So when you use `console.log(tblLoc)` and when the value is retrieved, `{}` is shown in the log.

  - When you want to see the retrieved value, for example, you can use `console.log(tblLoc.getElement().asText().getText())`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
const doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/document/d/###/edit");
const body = doc.getBody();
const tblLoc = body.findText("\\$");
console.log(tblLoc.getElement().asText().getText())
```

#### Reference:

- [findText(searchPattern)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern)

Comment: Thank you!  That works very well - though I am still unsure why the '//' is necessary!

Comment: @PhilTilson Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.